# What does this warning mean? It happens every time I restart the node process

Tags: javascript, node.js

The warning:

```
(process:3380): GLib-GIO-WARNING **: 12:47:10.778: Unexpectedly, UWP app `HaukeGtze.NotepadEditor_1.795.1.0_x64__6bk20wvc8rfx2' (AUMId `HaukeGtze.NotepadEditor_6bk20wvc8rfx2!notepad') supports 182 extensions but has no verbs
```

I think the part before the word 'Unexpectedly' is the time, but what does the rest mean?

The last thing I was doing before this started was installing canvas with `npm install canvas --save`.

So is there a way for me to stop this?

I also noticed it says NotepadEditor there but what does that have to do with anything? It doesn't crash the process, and doesn't seem to affect anything, but it's annoying.
**EDIT** : it was caused by require('canvas') rather than installing it. So how can I require it without getting the warning?

Comment: Not sure what it means, but here is where it is coming from: https://github.com/frida/glib/blob/master/gio/gwin32appinfo.c#L3477

Comment: I feel it's because a Linux native module is being run on windows. Not sure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I encountered similar problem but with "`Microsoft.Print3D`" and "`Microsoft.DesktopAppInstaller`" instead.

### **The cause:**

IDK xD. It does say in the https://github.com/frida/glib/blob/master/gio/gwin32appinfo.c#L3477 niry posted before, that:

> ...for 100% correct handling we (GLib and GIO) need to remember which extensions
> (handlers) support which verbs, and each handler gets its own copy of
> the verb object, since our design is handler-centric, not
> verb-centric. The app also gets a list of verbs, but without handlers
> it would have no idea which verbs can be used with which extensions.

As of why it has no verbs, I suspect it has something to do with registers and installation due to the solution I provided below.

### **My Solution: Reinstalling the problematic app**

Before you begin, this only fixed my problem with Print3D and made the problem with DesktopAppInstaller worse; it now says "Failed to open manifest..." and I had to reinstall it, which also removes the problem with canvas.

1. Run Powershell with Administrator privilege
2. Get-AppXPackage "`HaukeGtze.NotepadEditor`" -allusers
3. If it exists, jump to number 4.

or

2. `Get-AppXPackage -allusers`
3. Find the problematic one (`HaukeGtze.NotepadEditor`) and note the NAME (not the package full name).
4. `Get-AppXPackage [name here] -allusers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}`

Comment: OK, so would it be Notepad, or Notepad++?

Comment: @MrMythical i guess Notepad++ but myself don't have that app registered in Get-AppXPackage (installed from 3rd party installer); you might have installed it from Windows Store.

Comment: I did install it from windows store

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when using Python weasyprint package. It was complaining about Windows PDF X app. GLib-GIO-WARNING **: 11:31:57.620: Unexpectedly, UWP app `6760NGPDFLab.PDFX_1.3.13.0_x64__sbe4t8mqwq93a'. I simply uninstalled the app and the problem went away.